# JGoodies: What is the nextLine() equivalent in FormBuilder

Tags: jgoodies

DefaultFormBuilder [has been deprecated](http://www.jgoodies.com/download/libraries/forms/RELEASE-NOTES.txt) in version of JGoodies 1.9.0. The suggested alternative is [FormBuilder](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/).

Old code using DefaultFormBuilder:

```
builder.appendSeparator("Autoset");
builder.append(description);
builder.nextLine();
```

New code using FormBuilder:

```
builder.addSeparator("Autoset").xy(1, 1);
builder.add(description).xy(1, 3);
```

Note that the positions of the added elements have to be explicitly given. Is this really necessary? Is there any equivalent of `append()` (without coordinates) and `nextLine()`?

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the DefaultFormBuilder has been widely abused in the projects I worked in. It was intended for very simple forms only. Often developers have added cursor operations that ended up in code that is hard to read - and needs two passes to understand the overall layout.

Therefore it has been deprecated.

The FormBuilder code should read:

> FormBuilder.create()
>      .columns("...")
>      .rows("...")
>      .addSeparator("Autoset").xy(1, 1)
>      .add(description)       .xy(1, 3)
>      .build();

Comment: My issue is that I don't care of the real Y position. I just want to add lines and JGoodies calculates the concrete coordinates by itself. Introducing `y` as variable and doing `y++` inbetween is IMHO also not good code, is it? - Maybe, this is the wrong place to discuss this.